# Django include templates problem, from 0.96 to 1.2

Tags: django

I using google app engine, in 0.96 I have no problem to include a template as following

```
{% include "../header.html" %}
```

However, in 1.2 the code above not functioning??

Any idea?

Comment: does it help to fully specify the path (e.g. "folder/folder2/header.html")?

Comment: @dolan no, I tried "/html/header.html", "html/header.html" both not working.

Comment: can you provide your TEMPLATE_LOADERS and TEMPLATE_DIRS settings.py entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `google.appengine.ext.webapp.template.render` doesn't use any user-configurable `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Instead it invents its own `TEMPLATE_DIRS` byt taking the directory of the given template and using that at `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. This means if you call `render("foo/bar/fie")` it will use `foo/bar` as your template directory and look up files from there.

Now, the change from 0.96 til 1.2 is that the file lookup switched from using `os.path.join` to using `django.utils._os.safe_join` which does not allow escape from the base directory using `../`.

I don't see any obvious way around this. It seems like you must call `render` with a file directly in your template directory and not in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

dkagedal is correct in his assessment of the problem, but there's is an easy workaround if you're not averse to monkeypatching:

```
try:
  # Bypass Django's safe_join for template paths since App Engine sandboxes the
  # filesystem anyway, and safe_join won't allow relative includes because
  # webapp.template always sets the template's parent directory as the "root",
  # rather than the app's real root directory.
  from django.utils import _os
  _os.safe_join = os.path.join
except ImportError:
  pass  # App is using a version of Django that doesn't use safe_join, it's OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that that's not working- it is the correct syntax for the tag...

How is it not working? Not bringing in the data at all? Error message?

Is header.html just regular the body sections of the html? or is it a full standalone html page? (ie does it have html, head, body, tags etc? or just h, p, etc?)

Maybe try using the {% ssi %} tag as documented here:
[SSI Template Tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi)

Comment: The header.html just regular portion of html, I have no problem to {% include "header.html" %}, with the "../", it just doesn't show anything.

Comment: have you tried adding your template subfolder to the TEMPLATE_DIRS in the settings.py file?

Comment: But there is no settings.py file (remember this is Google App Engine, just using the Django templating library). I tried adding a setting.py, but it didn't seem to matter.