# django template on google app engine with include statement

Tags: google-app-engine

This question [was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144138/django-include-templates-problem-from-0-96-to-1-2) before but didn't seem to be answered. So I am asking it again.

On Google App Engine with python, I have two directories under the root of my application: `/templates` and `/static/files`. Suppose `base.html` is in `/templates` and it contains the following template statement:

```
{% include "privacy.html" %}
```

The above statement will work if file `privacy.html` is also in directory `/templates`. However, if `privacy.html` is moved to directory `/static/files`, the following statement would not work (nothing is included):

```
{% include "/static/files/privacy.html" %}
```

Why and how to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: The second answer on that question (monkeypatching) seems worth trying. According to the first answer, there is no simple way to specify that relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using a static file handler in app.yaml for the `/static/files` folder. In which case, read this:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers

Essentially the static files are put on a separate filesystem when deployed, and won't be accessible by your app.

Here's a few workarounds:

- don't put the template in the a static files folder.  That generally doesn't even make sense since you don't serve templates directly to the end user.
- Duplicate the folder if necessary, so that only one copy has a static handler.
- Use a symlink to 'duplicate' the folder.